# Timeout while using MockWebServer?

Tags: android, mockwebserver

I try to use [MockWebServer](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver) to the various responses to my API.
I have made a simple example just to try that what I would like to do is a working method.

Isn't the **mockWebServer** meant to 'mock' the endpoint of my http connections? Like a real server? Whenever I try to make a call **I got UnknownHostException.**

Am I using it wrong? **Isn't it supposed to just replace a server's response? (mock it)**

**E D I T:**

I have internet permission in manifest.

I use:

```
 androidTestImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.9.1'
```

**Code:**

```
 @Test
    public void myTest() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String url = "http://some-mock-url.com";

        MockWebServer server = new MockWebServer();
        server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody("Something not valid JSON response"));
        server.start();

        server.url(url);

        final CountDownLatch signal = new CountDownLatch(1);

        AndroidNetworking.get(url)
                .addQueryParameter("some_key", "some_value12345")
                .addHeaders("token", "token_1231234")
                .build()
                .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {

                                     @Override
                                     public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                         signal.countDown();
                                         Log.i("Response", "jsonObject: " + response);
                                     }

                                     @Override
                                     public void onError(ANError anError) {
                                         signal.countDown();
                                         Log.i("Response", "error: " + anError.getMessage());
                                     }
                                 }
                );
        signal.await();
    }
```

**Logcat:**

> com.androidnetworking.error.ANError: java.net.UnknownHostException: 
>   Unable to resolve host "some-mock-url.com": No address associated with
>   hostname

Comment: Check your internet connection permission.

Comment: @Shailesh I have internet permission.

Comment: Check this one because i am unable to open your url in browser  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951466/java-net-unknownhostexception-unable-to-resolve-host-url-no-address-associ

Comment: @Shailesh The url is a fake one. There is no real address like that. Isn't this is the purplose of a mock server? To use a 'fake' endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an example when the order is reversed.

So instead of setting an URL to the Mock server, you have to **set the Mock server's url to the actual URL**, so like:

```
myAPIsURL= mockWebServer.url("/").toString();
```

And not

<s>mockWebServer.url(myAPIsURL);</s>

Comment: did it work for you?
i am trying to do as you suggested, i still get the same issue.
please suggest if you think there is any other possibility to solve this

Comment: @Kaveri Yes, as the *answer* states.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has the same problem, `MockWebServer` is from the same dependency of `OKHttp` so they both need to have the same dependency version.

Answer (score -1):

It was a proxy issue for me .
i followed this solution.
I am not getting the unknown host exception now.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41714851/5856146